# software center lists mutiple entries of okular install and reader

Tags: software-center, okular

Recently I noticed by accident that I have multiple entries for the okular document viewer in the Software Center. Four of five appear to be identical.  Also listed are a host of okular active-documentviewer readers.  Is this normal?

```
3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu 14.04 LTS
intel core i5 CPU 650 64 bit
```

*Why are some applications listed more than once in Software Center?*

Comment: Had this issue with other apps also.It is not only okular.